# Disabling standard registration login with username/email and password?

Tags: login, user-registration, wp-login-form

Would it be possible to remove both the login and password fields from the login/registration form?

I'm currently trying to implement logging in/registration for my users using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/

It allows them to login/register with an account from a few different websites.

If possible I'd like to keep the standard login for admins and staff so they don't have to use their social accounts, which in the event that they might be compromised, could end up locking them out of the backend, unable to perform maintenance tasks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to hook `register_form`.  It will require parsing the html and removing elements manually, something like this should point you in the right direction.

```
function removeFormElements(){
    $form = ob_get_contents();
    //manipulate $form to remove the elements with something like either regex or the php DOM parser
    ob_get_clean()
    echo $form;
}
add_action('register_form', 'removeFormElements');
```

I believe your oAuth plugin is probably handling what needs to be done in the `registration_errors` hook to allow a registration without a username/password, but if it isn't you would also need a function to prevent an error from being thrown due to a lack of required input.